# ngTagsInput/auto-complete ( AngularJS )

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display a tag-input field with auto-complete, so that if the user enter some text in the input field, the available tags appear as suggestions in the dropdown. Everything works fine so far:

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tags-input ng-model="tags" add-on-paste="true">
        <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
    <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
</body>
```

AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
            return $http.get(Routing.generate('my_route_to_json_data'));
        }
    });
```

Here is the working result:
[image]

Problem is when I try to add `maxResultsToShow="4"` or `minLength="1"` attributes to  , they don't work, and I still get the same result.

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tags-input ng-model="tags" add-on-paste="true">
            <auto-complete maxResultsToShow="4" loadOnEmpty=true minLength="1" source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
    <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
</body>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<auto-complete max-results-to-show="4" load-on-empty="true" min-length="1" source="loadTags($query)">`

In angular, you have to use dash-case in the html tags and camelCase in the JS code, they are automatically converted.